# Daisy chaining capacity for USB 3.0

Tags: usb-3, daisychaining

I am trying to figure out how many USB 3.0 devices I can daisy chain together and provide an adequate (5V) power supply to. For instance Device #1 (D1), plugs into my laptop and my laptop keeps it charged. Then Device #2 (D2) plugs into D1 and keeps charged. So on and so forth until some capacity/threshold is reached.

**What is this capacity, what is magic about this number (why is this the magic number for max # of chained devices), and where can I find documentation on this?**

Comment: USB does not support "daisy chaining".  The setup you describe would require both devices be host devices.  Device 2 wouldn't be visible to the laptop if it was hooked up to device 1.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks @Ramhound - doo any other cables support this kind of power/charge daisy chaining? FireWire maybe?

Comment: Yes;  Firewire supports daisy chaining.  Thunderbolt also does